# bitcoin alternatives for solo mining on an average laptops

Tags: client, litecoin, mining-profitability

Bitcoins take a lot of time, what are the alternatives? i've heard of litecoin but there are so many outhere so what would be the best choice for an average pc?

Comment: It just won't be worth to mine on an average PC, unless you do it for recreational/educative purposes.

Comment: @Lohoris i guess you're right, even litecoin isn't working on my laptop

Comment: I'm sorry! There still are many options out there, depending on how much you want to invest, on how technical you want to be, on how much you want to trust people, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I feel that this is a very open-ended question, and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to mine any currency that uses the scrypt hashing algorithm and sell your earnings for BTC.  There are many to choose from and sites like [Coinchoose](http://coinchoose.com/) can help you determine which is the most profitable to mine and sell for BTC.

CPU mining isn't going to get you much but you can make some BTC this way.  If you have a GPU in your PC, make sure you run the right mining software that can utilize your GPU as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pay the electric bills and leave your computer on the whole day -such as in your office computer, which you must be able to connect to at any time- then you could try mining some Litecoins. Don't expect to get rich, though, at current difficulty you won't get more than 1 or 2 LTC per month. Still, it could be a start. Then you could buy some Bitcoins with your Litecoins...

The legality and morality of this should be left at your consideration, though - since you'd be leaving the computer on the whole day, anyway, and electricity consumption won't increase way too much... you'd not robbing (so to say) too much off the company.
Still, you'd be using your work tools for a private benefit, however small, which wouldn't look well in the eyes of your employer should you get caught.

If you're doing it on your private machine, unless you have a Raspberry PI or some similar ultra-low consumption computer, you wouldn't even recover your costs... I'd say it's not worth it. You'd be better off getting a GPU and installing some photovoltaic cells on your ceiling...